# Rails query to find overlapping models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `Profile` which belongs to `Integration` through `IntegrationProfiles`

The Integration model has column `provider`

I want to query to find profiles that fit two different or overlap within two providers.

```
Profile.joins(:integrations).
where("integrations.provider = 'csv'").
where("integrations.provider = 'kickstarter'")

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Although there is a few profiles that are within `kickstarter` and CSV.

Updated:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :integration_profiles
    has_many :integrations, through: :integration_profiles
end

class Integration < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :integration_profiles
    has_many :profiles, through: :integration_profiles
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be the best way to do it:

```
pcsv = Profile.joins(:integrations).where(integrations: { provider: 'csv' })

pk = Profile.joins(:integrations).where(integrations: { provider: 'kickstarter' })

ps = pk & pcsv
```

Which is not efficient and results in an array instead of an ActiveRecord resource. Not the most efficient but it may do for now

Answer (score 2):

The two where method calls would generate SQL `and` conditions, i.e. `where integrations.provider = 'csv' and integrations.provider = 'kickstarter'`. What you want is an `or` condition between them, or you could use `in` as:

```
Profile.joins(:integrations).where("integrations.provider in(?)", [ 'csv', 'kickstarter' ])
```

Or, different syntactically:

```
Profile.joins(:integrations).where(integrations: { provider: ['csv', 'kickstarter'] })
```

Comment: See updated code. A profile can have many integrations. I need to find profiles that have integrations which have provider kickstarter AND csv. An or only brings profiles that have either or, I need the overlap.

Answer (score 2):

**Why it does not work?** Your 2 where statements does not make sense. You ask to find records:

```
WHERE provider = 'csv' AND provider = 'kickstarter'
```

Chaining several `.where` method will actually joins the conditions with a `AND`.

---

**How to fix this?** We want a `OR` condition here, that can be done with this:

```
Profile.joins(:integrations).where(integrations: { provider: ['csv', 'kickstarter'] })
```

This will actually generate WHERE statement like this:

```
WHERE intergrations.provider IN ('csv', 'kickstarter')
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
WHERE intergrations.provider = 'csv' OR  intergrations.provider = 'kickstarter'
```

Comment: See updated code. A profile can have many integrations. I need to find profiles that have integrations which have provider kickstarter AND csv. An or only brings profiles that have either or, I need the overlap.

Comment: Oh, I see... This is a complex SQL query, with 2 sub-queries, one to catch the integration having provider = 'csv', the other one catching 'kickstarter', and test the presence of the result of the 2 sub-queries.

Comment: any ideas how to make it happen?

Comment: No I don't ... I made some researches, but I can't figure it out.